# How to get coordinates of intersection between a plane and an object (using python API)?

Tags: python, coordinates, intersection

[image: an example]

Like showing above, I would like to get the coordinates of intersection between an object and a cube(the cube also could be a plane).

That's to say, I want to get the intersection coordinates in the green circle.
Does anyone know how to implement using Blender python API?

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated!!!

PS: The "cube" or "plane" is not necessary, cuz the coordinate I really want is the coordinates on the object surface given a z-coordination. For example, given the plane's z-coordinate is -10m, I want to know the verties' coordinates at -10m which lie on the surface of the object.
[image]

***PPS@20230222:***
TL;DR;
What I tried to do is a workaround of [this problem](https://blenderartists.org/t/creating-an-outer-shell-on-a-mesh/670239)

The original problem I want to solve is to convert a complex, non-manifold model (let's say "target model") into a model that can be 3D printed. ([This is an example model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gcDr5oqrDaFTOeLH50yPMSP-yNEtHfCe/view?usp=share_link)) I just need to have the "shell" (or the outermost shape) of the model, and I don't need it to be very precise. (I think this is the problem X)

I tried some other solutions, like shrinkwrap (too rough), clean non-manifold using the 3D print addon. None of these work ideally.

Thus, to solve X, I think I can first cut the target model into pieces, and fill in some small-enough and solid cubes inside of the pieces, layer by layer, thus I will get a solid and manifold model afterwards. (This is the problem Y)

To do this, I need to get the boundary of the target model at each point I want to place the cubes. So I think I may get the boundary through intersect a plane/cube/line with the model, so that the boundary of the target model can be get by the intersection coordinates.

To be more specific, check [this example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nagXOp5NbRinrp3W6lBIqca0UIjzP322/view?usp=share_link). I cut the magazine of the gun model, and added some disired cubes (2 layers) into it manually. This is what I think can be achieved by solving problem Y, and thus solve problem X.

And here I am, I was stuck there getting the intersection coordinates.

So is there another way to solove the original problem?

Comment: Could you provide more info about what this is for? Why do you need this? What are you trying to achieve? I am asking because this sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) kind of situation. Providing more context might be very useful to avoid this.

Comment: Thank you for replying @MartynasŽiemys
I will provide more info above.

Comment: This is not the correct way to make 3d models for 3d printing. In order to 3d print something, you need a good 3d model with tidy geometry. What you have in the shared .blend file is no good for 3d printing at all, because the model has holes, nonplanar n-gons, non-manifold and overlapping geometry and even parts floating inside the volume of the model - basically almost all possible things that one should avoid when modelling for 3d printing.

Comment: There is already Voxel Remesh feature in Blender that does what you want to do, but it will likely not work on the model, because it's just not good enough. Even if it works, it will reduce the quality even further and you will not reach good results with 3d printing something like this.

Comment: I can only recommend looking for a model that would be made for 3d printing, or remodeling it yourself. That requires 3d modelling skills and unfortunately, if you don't have them, it might take a few months at least to learn. I think you should put your effort into that instead of attempting very complex scripting that will most definitely fail anyway and might take comparable amount of time in the end.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an XY problem and answers to it can not solve the real issue.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway. I think I may try it a bit more time. If not working I may turn my direction.

Comment: Hi, sdsy888. I have to agree with @MartynasŽiemys. I think your most fruitful course with this question would be to start from scratch, stating the _problem_ from the get-go, as economically as possible, rather than the problems-with-your-attempted-solution. If you can edit to clean this up, we can re-open. Or you can re-post.  Nothing personal, just trying to give you (and the rest of us) the best crack at getting good answers.

Comment: alright, thanks. Btw, I got lots of such models, and thus redraw from scratch woundn't be possible. I will continue to find solutions, and may edit after I did.